# Rails: Displaying a user post form_for on a user page with nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a facebook clone, and I'm trying to have a text area on each user's page to allow them to make posts. I've tried a whole bunch of different things with no success, but right now I am getting this error when trying to access the user's show page:

```
 First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

with this code:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :friends, only: [:index, :destroy]
   resources :posts

   resources :friend_requests
     devise_for :users
     devise_scope :user do
       root 'devise/sessions#new'
   end

  resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do
     resources :posts
  end

  get 'about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  end
```

---

```
 _post_form.html.erb

 <%= form_for [@user, @post] do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content, size: "60x12", placeholder: "What do you want to say?" %>
<%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
   class PostsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @posts = Post.all
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end

def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
        flash[:success] = "Posted!"
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Post could not be submitted"
        redirect_to users_path
    end
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content)
end
end
```

---

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
    @users = User.all
end

def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

end
```

---

```
 users/show.html.erb

 <h4>You are signed in as <%= current_user.email %>! </h4>

 <% if @user == current_user %>
 <%= render "notifications" %>
 <%= render 'shared/post_form' %> 
 <% end %>

 <%= params.inspect %>
 <%= current_user.id %>
```

---

```
server log:
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
FriendRequest Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "friend_requests".* FROM "friend_requests"  WHERE "friend_requests"."friend_id" = $1 ORDER BY "friend_requests"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["friend_id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1000]]
Rendered users/_notifications.html.erb (2.0ms)
Rendered shared/_post_form.html.erb (3.0ms)
Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (10.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 23ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be  empty):
1: <%= form_for [@user, @post] do |f| %>
2:  <%= f.text_area :content, size: "60x12", placeholder: "What do you want to say?" %>
3:  <%= f.submit "Post" %>
4: <% end %>     

  app/views/shared/_post_form.html.erb:1:in  `_app_views_shared__post_form_html_erb___99030300856795657_70237723952000'
  app/views/users/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb___3196827877852207953_70237724137160'
 Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-   5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
 Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-  5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
```

Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (6.7ms)
     Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-   5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.0ms)
     Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
      Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
       Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-  `5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb   within rescues/layout (96.4ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that your form is having a problem rendering on the user's show page.  If you have this form w/ nested resource setup like this:

```
form_for [@user, @post]
```

It means your form needs access to both the `@user` and the `@post` instance variable whereever the form is to be rendered.  In this case, it is in the show action in your users controller.  So your **users controller** should have something like this:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @post = @user.posts.build
end
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `_post_form` is loaded when you go to your `posts#new` route which is handled by this posts controller action:

```
def new
    @post = Post.new
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

Nested routes (in this case user > post) place the parent resource's id in the param `resource_id`, in you case it would be `params[:user_id]`. So, essentially, change this line:

```
@user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

...to:

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
```

That will access the correct id in the params and will cause an exception if no user was found (by using `find` instead of `find_by`), that will alert you to the any problem before you get to the view rendering. In your case the `@user` was nil and you got the form_for error you posted.

**Update**

I see from your logs you are going to the `users#show` action, which is this one:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

as you can see, you're not setting the `@post` variable which you're passing to the form here:

```
form_for [@user, @post]
```

Add this to you action:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @post = Post.new
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried implementing the change you suggested, but I still wind up with the same error when trying to access the user's page

Comment: Post your new code please, also what path you're navigating to, and your server log for that action

Comment: okay I edited with server log info. As for the path, I thought that I don't need to supply one because rails will see the form_for stuff and decide if its a post or patch and where to post it to based on [@user, @post] ?

Comment: I meant, what path are _you_ going to in the browser to see the rendered form?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to get the user's show page to load with the post form partial